# pycharm project works on 'run' but pyinstaller --onefile gives errors related to pulp

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pulp

I've been working on a project where a user can upload a file for analysis via pulp. When I run the project in pycharm it works fine, but after I build a --onefile with pyinstaller... I get the following traceback

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
  File "example.py", line 29, in get_file
  File "pydfs_lineup_optimizer\lineup_optimizer.py", line 351, in optimize
  File "pydfs_lineup_optimizer\solvers\pulp_solver.py", line 39, in solve
  File "site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 1664, in solve
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

Here is a piece of the code I'm having an issue with:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import csv
import time
import os, sys
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.font import Font




def get_file():
    global file
    file = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()

def run_it():
    from pydfs_lineup_optimizer import Site, Sport, get_optimizer
    optimizer = get_optimizer(Site.FANDUEL, Sport.BASEBALL)
    optimizer.load_players_from_CSV(file)
    lineup_generator = optimizer.optimize(3)
    with open('Lineup.csv', "w") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
        for lineup in lineup_generator:
            writer.writerow([lineup])

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("600x337")
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    baseDir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    baseDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

image = Image.open(os.path.join(baseDir, 'baseball.jpg'))

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
L0 = Label(top, image=photo)

L2 = Button(top, text="UPLOAD", fg="blue", font=font2, command=get_file).grid(row=1, column=4)
L3 = Button(top, text="RUN", fg="blue", font=font2, command=run_it).grid(row=2, column=4)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Update... I no longer believe this to be a lack of adding a dependency to the build. Stuart, I read your google forum remarks (similar to your help here), and there's a couple things that make me think this a tkinter issue instead of build issue. 1) Again, the project as it stands works perfectly fine in PyCharm... just the dist that pyinstaller spits out isn't functional. 2) I have hooked everything short of the C:\ directory to this thing and to no avail. And 3) the pulp library already had the cbc file, with Win,OS,and Linux versions. I really think something happens to the CSV uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulp requires the cbc.exe file to be available to use to actually solve the lp problems.

Unfortunately pyinstaller doesn't pick that up by default and you need to figure out a way to package the cbc.ex file then tell the COIN_CMD() solver where to find it.

Do this by using `COIN_CMD(path=<your_path_here>)`

Comment: Ok I’ll try that. Just add to .spec binaries and compile again. Thanks man, let you know if it handles my issue. But if that’s the case, why is it solving in pycharm?

Comment: Stuart, I've added the exe to my spec file, and tried multiple ways to put path into the COIN_CMD() solver (this part I'm still a bit lost on). Still can't get a good bundle. Pretty lost on this one. I'll get to set a bounty before long, so maybe it won't be too long. Thanks for your help. Oh and one more thing, there's a lot of posts that state that I need a coinor install... I can't find one for windows (or at least pip can't find it).

Comment: Hey man, go ahead and answer the question so I can give you your bounty!! Huge help man, a blessing indeed, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Chris Brocious
I know this is already answered, but sounded like you still had issues with it.

What I did was

1. took the cbc.exe from the python site package folder (pulp\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe) and copied it to the folder that pyinstaller generates.
2. I modified my code to look for the path in the current working directory as my executable.

   cwd = os.getcwd()
   cwdcbc=f"{cwd}\cbc.exe"
   solver = pl.COIN_CMD(path=cwdcbc)

The end result was a zip file that had two files in it, the cbc.exe and myapp.exe and runs perfectly as long as the user extracts the files to any folder.